# how to replace tags <Media> and <Media.Body> in react-bootstrap 2.2.3?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I have such React-bootstrap code example:

```
import Media from 'react-bootstrap/Media';

const Product = (props) => {
    return (
     <div>
         <Media>
            <img
            width={64}
            height={64}
            className="mr-3"
            src={props.data.imageUrl}
            alt="Product Imag"
            />
            <Media.Body>
                <h5> {props.data.productName} </h5>
                {props.data.releasedDate }
                <Rating
                rating={props.data.rating} numOfReviews={props.data.numOfReviews}
                />
                <p> {props.data.description} </p>
            </Media.Body>
        </Media>
     </div>
    );
}
```

but seems as in react-bootstrap version 2.2.3 where made some changes and now there aren't tags  and <Media.Body> anymore

So how I can replace this tags according to the current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the final solution for this case looks like this:

```
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from './Rating';

const styles={
    cardStyle:{
       'flex-direction': 'row',
       'align-items': 'center'
    },
    cardImgStyle: {
        width: '64px',
        height: '64px',
    }
}

const Product = (props) => {
    return (
     <div>
         <Card style={styles.cardStyle}>
            <Card.Img style={styles.cardImgStyle}
            className="ms-3"
            src={props.data.imageUrl}
            alt="Product Imag"
            />
            <Card.Body>
                <h5> {props.data.productName} </h5>
                {props.data.releasedDate }
                <Rating
                rating={props.data.rating} numOfReviews={props.data.numOfReviews}
                />
                <p> {props.data.description} </p>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
     </div>
    );
    }

export default Product;
```

Comment: Please add more description as well as code.

Comment: Please mark your question as solved

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I would say that the Card or maybe Image components are what you're looking for:

[Card](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/)

[Image](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/images/#images)

Looks like you'd just have refactor `Media` to `Card` in the above example to get it working.

Comment: thanks for idea, but this tags aren't working if image should be placed on left side of the block (like in two columns)
maybe there are some other options/tags?

Answer (score 1):

As @arfi720 has mentioned, it looks like you can migrate to *Card* and *Image* components. Because bootstrap is mostly css/styling, you can change it to everything you want. Or you dont need to use something, that is not suitable for you (here *Card.Img*). I've just created similar component few days ago and put the *Image* in *Card.Body*, as it already stacks horizontally:

```
<Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
    <Card.Body>
        <Image src="holder.js/100x50" className="me-2" />
        Test
    </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-ishizaka-l70ftr?file

Comment: thanks, but it looks like workarround - there aren't obvious way to place <Card.Img> and <Card.Body> in 2 columns horizontally one by one (and if not use this tags - so what is the reason to use the <Card> tag at all? :))

Comment: look into the class "card" (in devTools for example) - it adds position, display, border, word-wrap etc etc. Of course you can create your own component with your own style, but this applies to nearly all of the react-bootstrap components - they are mostly only styling/css solutions.

Comment: well I finally done this in such way (as you recommended):

const styles={
    cardStyle:{
       'flex-direction': 'row',
       'align-items': 'center'
    },
    cardImgStyle: {
        width: '64px',
        height: '64px',
    }
}

const Product = (props) => {
    return (
     <div>
         <Card style={styles.cardStyle}>
            <Card.Img style={styles.cardImgStyle}
            className="ms-3"

***

But I have worries that this way isn't "consistent" cause I didn't used only Bootstrap/React inbuilt classes/tags/properties so for me it looks as "hardcoding" :)